# Help for structuring pertinent GLM model

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model

A little background. I have a territory in which I've recorded the position of 10 individuals at regular 5-minute intervals. This territory is divided into 3 zones A, B and C. Around this territory are two zones accessible to visitors, V1 and V2.

Each line of my df corresponds to a 5-minute interval, and my variables are as follows:

- nA: number of individuals in zone A at time T.
- nB and nC the same for the other two zones.
- V1T the number of visitors present in V1 at time T.
- V1N the number of new visitors appearing in the interval.
- V1Max the maximum number of visitors present in the interval simultaneously.
- V2T, V2N and V2Max the same for zone V2.
- Md: the time of day: Morning or Afternoon.

I'm looking to model how visitors affect the distribution of individuals by zone. What interests me and what I'm trying to model is :

1. the effect of V1T, V1N and V1Max separately on nA
2. the effect of V2T, V2N and V1Max separately on nB
3. the effect of V1T and V2T separately and simultaneously on nC
4. the effect of V1N and V2N separately and simultaneously on nC
5. the effect of V1Max and V2Max separately and simultaneously on nC

For the code I thought it might be relevant to make GLM as nA/B and C are counting variables ? for 1 and 2 possibly in this form, but without much conviction:

```
Glm1 <- glm(nA~V1T*V1N*V1Max, data=df, family=poisson)
```

Then for 3/4 and 5, I don't really know how to structure my model's code. And for each of the models, I have no idea how to integrate and take into account Md ...

Comment: I don't understand the situation you are modelling. But some thoughts. a) You have ten individuals (nA + nB + nC = 10), which can be in only one zone at a time. So that's a **multinomial distribution**. b) There may be temporal correlation between each window, if they're taken 5 minutes apart (e.g. how quickly can individuals move between areas). c) can you clarify the V variables? e.g. is V1T + V1N = V1Max?

Comment: Hello
a- yes, that's the case! Does this change the way I have to structure my model?
b- I'm not sure I understand the nature of this remark, but yes, obviously each series of observations is linked in time. As the objective is to understand the effect of the presence of visitors around the territory on the distribution of individuals, I need to compare the abundance of individuals in each zone at regular time intervals.
c- the V variables are those linked to the presence of visitors and are independent of each other.

Comment: e.g. I take an initial record of the position of all the individuals at a given time T. At the same time T, I also know the number of visitors present in each of the two zones (V1T/V2T).
5 minutes later (let's call this moment T+1) I take a second reading of the position of the individuals, so a second value of (V1T/ V2T) ... and so on.
The VMax value indicates the maximum simultaneous number of visitors present between T and T+1.
While VN corresponds to the number of new visitors who passed through the two zones between T and T+1.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full "how to do it" answer, but some thoughts and leads.

1. You need to account for there being 10 individuals. This could be done either by a multinomial model (more complete), or binomial (less complete, but simpler). Using a Poisson, which does not have an upper limit, can give nonsensical results.
2. You should test for autocorrelation (i.e. if in a five minute window $i$, there are $n_{A(i)}$ individuals in territory $A$, there may be a relationship between that and the next window $i+1$'s count, $n_{A(i+1)}$.
3. The $V$ variables are likely highly correlated and it might be difficult to elucidate the impact of them simultaneously.

It might not be feasible to account for all three points at once, but I'll try to get you on the right track.

### 1. Upper limit of individuals

There are always ten individuals. Therefore, you should use a model which accounts for this. The two obvious options are binomial, and multinomial.

In a multinomial model, the response variable would be the vector $(n_A,n_B,n_C)$ and your predictor would be some combination of the $V$ variables, depending on the particular thing you explore. This properly accounts for the relationship between $n$ for territories - e.g. we know if $n_A$ and $n_B$ are "high", then $n_C$ is going to be "low". It also allows you to model all three counts at the same time, which maximises the amount of information available. The downside is that it's a more complex method, and it's harder to find packages which implement it.

In a binomial model (let's say for territory $A$), the response is a vector $(n_A, n_B+n_C)$, while the predictors again are some combination of the $V$ variables. There are many more ways to implement this in R, but it's a simpler model.

### 2. Autocorrelation

This should at least be tested for. If autocorrelation exists, and it's not accounted for, your estimates will be overly confident. A number of R GLMM (generalised linear mixed model) packages have options for AR-1 autocorrelation.

### 3. $V$ variables' correlation

There may be a multicollinearity issue. There may not be. But watch out for high correlation between the various $V$ variables, because that is something that can lead to estimation problems and model reliability issues. I'm not super familiar with techniques to deal with this - some ways off the top of my head are PCA, and regressing *predictors* against each other to remove multicollinearity. Or, just simplifying the model so that you don't have a model with both correlated variables in it.

### How to implement this?

You would look to fit models that look like (this is pseudocode, not working code). A good start might be:

```
mdl_1 <- model((n_A, n_B, n_C) ~ V1T, family = multinomial_or_binomial, correlation = AR1(~ time_window_d))
mdl_2 <- model((n_A, n_B, n_C) ~ V1N + V2N, family = multinomial_or_binomial, correlation = AR1(~ time_window_d))
## etc...
```

You can test whether things like AR-1 is necessary, via things like AIC(c) or the goodness of fit of `DHARMa` residual plots.

R packages that might support this:

- `mgcv::gamm` - this supports multinomial or binomial response, and AR-1 autocorrelation
- `glmmTMB::glmmTMB` - this supports binomial (not multinomial) response, and AR-1 autocorrelation
- `VGAM::vglm` - this supports multinomial or binomial repsonse, but no autocorrelation (I think)

One more note: you have a lot of thing that you want to explore. If you are doing formal hypothesis tests, you need to account for [multiple comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem). If you are not doing formal testing, then using a combination of AICc/`DHARMa` residual plots should be adequate.